# A generic interface with type constraints accepting a default type

Tags: typescript, generics

I've created a simple generic interface in typescript

```
interface DateAdapter<T> {
  clone(): T;
}
```

and I have a simple class which implements said interface

```
class StandardDateAdapter implements DateAdapter<StandardDateAdapter> {
  clone: () => StandardDateAdapter;
}
```

I then have a generic `Options` interface which accepts a type extending `DateAdapter`. By default, I'd like the type argument to be `StandardDateAdapter` so I set it up like so:

```
interface Options<T extends DateAdapter<T> = StandardDateAdapter> {
  until?: T;
}
```

Unfortunately, typescript doesn't like this and is throwing an error

```
Type 'StandardDateAdapter' does not satisfy the constraint 'DateAdapter<T>'.
  Types of property 'clone' are incompatible.
    Type '() => StandardDateAdapter' is not assignable to type '() => T'.
      Type 'StandardDateAdapter' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

Any ideas how I can work around this? Is this a bug? Thanks!

*note: `DateAdapter` is only generic because I want the return type of `clone()` to equal the type of the class implementing `DateAdapter`. I had initially tried `clone(): this;` in the DateAdapter, but typescript was smart enough to realize that StandardDateAdapter#clone() returning `new StandardDateAdapter` !== `this`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like when TypeScript checks that the constraint is satisfied when `T` is at its default, it isn't smart enough to replace occurrences of `T` in the constraint with the default.  IMO, this would be reasonable to file as an issue and let the TypeScript team decide what to do about it; I searched and didn't find an existing issue as of 2018-07-28.

This is the best workaround I could find:

```
interface Options<T extends DateAdapter<T> = StandardDateAdapter & DateAdapter<T>> {
  until?: T;
}
```

Then the default is effectively `StandardDateAdapter & DateAdapter<{}>`, which looks ugly but is assignable to and from `StandardDateAdapter`, so hopefully it will work for everything you need.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to wait a few days to give other people a chance to respond, but, assuming someone else doesn't know of a better solution, I'll mark this as correct.